# how can i install downloaded ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

i have installed the gem it shows the error:

```
 gem install --local /home/harish/Downloads/json-1.8.0.gem 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing /home/harish/Downloads/json-1.8.0.gem:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /home/harish/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/harish/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming your on a Debian derivitive. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9-dev
```

For Fedora, try this:

```
sudo yum install ruby-devel
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me on fedora 20, ruby 2.0.0, to do "sudo gem install mechanize" and install mechanize-2.7.3.